# Installing Tensorflow on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.0 in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, python-3.7

I'm trying to use [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) on Windows 10  64-bit OS with [JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE and [Python 3.7.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/). I've cloned https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/TensorFlow_Tut_1_Installation_and_First_Progs to my directory. Before I used  [Python 3.5.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/), so I've changed `Path` in `Environment Variables` and `File/Settings` in `Project Interpreter` to `Python 3.7.0 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe)` so basic python code works, but when I'm trying to run `add_two_numbers_via_TensorFlow.py` code, which contains `import tensorflow as tf` it gives error:

```
"C:/Users/User/Desktop/TensorFlow/TensorFlow_Tut_1_Installation_and_First_Progs/add_two_numbers_via_TensorFlow.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

so I have to install with `Command Prompt` `Run as Administrator` `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` or `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`, but error is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow Collecting tensorflow   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I'm not sure what I have to install, maybe additionally `Python 3.6.x 64-bit`

Also I've tried to install `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`, but in result I have another error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

**Edit 1:**

Attempt to install from PyCharm with 
[Python 3.6.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/):

[image]

[Installing TensorFlow on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) says that I have to download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#download) for Python 3.6 version. I'm not sure if it is solution and reason of error

**Edit 2:**

[Python-3.6.6-amd64.exe](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/) properties, which is [Windows x86-64 executable installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow is not available for Python 3.7 yet. For now you can go back to Python 3.6 or 3.5 and check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022) for more information.

Comment: Hello, I got same error (last in my question post) with Python 3.5.1

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with Python versioning since Python 3.7 now should be working with Tensorflow. More likely it's a CUDA and cuDNN problem since it's tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure why you need `python 3.7`. But generally people don't mess with the installed interpreters on their machine. Instead they create a `virtual environment`. This allows you to have a python interpreter with the version you need. It also keeps all your packages separate. You should create a new `virtual env` for every project. Using a virtual machine you won't have to run anything as root which is nice as it is safer.

Pycharm let's you create one when you create you project or you can go to `settings>project>project interpreter`. By clicking the gear icon you can change your current interpreter to another one or you can create a new virtualenv.

If you are using Pycharm there is a specific way to install packages.

Go to `settings>project>project interpreter`. There you can click the `+` to add a new package like `tensorflow`.

Comment: Hello, I got same error (last in my question post) with Python 3.5.1

Comment: Did you try to install it within Pycharm, or again with pip3? You should use Pycharm for it.

Comment: I've edited my question with result of installations from Pycharm, result is `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement`

Comment: Your python is a 32 bit application. Tensorflow only supports 64 bit.

Comment: I have edited question with print screen of python-3.6.6-amd64.exe properties, seem like it 64 bit

Comment: Pycharm is using another interpreter then the one you put a screenshot from. You can try changing the pycharm interpreter to the 64 bit one.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and i was able to sort out this way :

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  pprint --proxy=http://username:password@doaminname.com:portnumber
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: doaminname.com:portnumber

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to configure with python 3.7. Use python 3.6. please use the virtual environment as mentioned above and make sure that is defined in the "Project  Interpreter" in PyCharm settings.

here are few simple instructions to configure using 3.6:

[configuring PyCharm for TensorFlow using python 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy2f6.png)

Comment: Add the instructions as text to your answer and not as screenshot.